# How to upgrade php to version 7.2

Tags: apt, php

my `phpinfo()` shows `php version 7.0.26`.

I want to upgrade it to php 7.2

I want to upgrade to phpversion 7.2.

```
sudo apt install php7.2
```

Doesn't update the apache php version. 
How can I update the apache php version?